# What jar/dex file provides the real implementation of the Android.jar

Tags: android, android-build, android-framework

I ran into some interesting problem after compiling the Android SDK source. I
tried to disassemble the resulting android.jar, but found that most
methods contained in that jar file are just a stub that does nothing
more than throwing a runtime exception, for example:

```
public void startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent, int);
Code:
0:  new #2; //class java/lang/RuntimeException
3:  dup
4:  ldc #3; //String Stub!
6:  invokespecial   #4; //Method java/lang/
RuntimeException."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
9:  athrow
```

I can understand there might be no need for Android.jar to contain the
real implementations of Android Framework, given it only serves as a
compile-time library for 3rd party apps. But my question is: what is
the Jar or Dex file(s) that provides the real implementation of android.jar? I
assume it should also be generated when compiling the SDK, am I right?

Thanks!
LL